# I want netinstall, but I can't!

Tags: netinstall

I want netinstall, but I can't!

Just because I don't have ethernet port at all!
And netinstall don't have wifi drivers!

Sounds awesome, right?

Comment: Is there a question? or is this just an off-topic rant?

Comment: The question is - how to fly if you don't have wings!

Comment: What wifi card (brand, type, chipset) do you have?

Comment: I have - intel AC 7265

Comment: @levgen... It is nice if you make your question clear enough.